# Space before colon in beamer captions

Tags: beamer, spacing, captions

As you can see below, LaTeX is formatting my captions like this: `Figure : caption`, while I would like them to be `Figure: caption`, without a space before colon. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{See, there's space before the colon.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which makes this:
[image]

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colon}{: }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{See, there's space before the colon.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beamer`s facilities instead of using `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }  %% note the space after :, not before
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{See, there's space before the colon.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Solution: add

```
\usepackage{captions}
\captionsetup{labelsep = colon}
```

to the preamble. However, this is still a bug, because it doesn't happen in other document classes.